# How do I remove left margin completely on css

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a image view fully on the window, so I don't want any margins. I tried looking for answers that said stuff like adding body margin or margin on everything to 0 but they don't work.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

or

```
*, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
```

or

```
.splash-page .main-wrap {
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```

or

```
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

This made the margin smaller, but there's still a margin on the left, both on the image and on the body text as you can see in this image:

[Browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgbGI.png)

Thanks a lot in advance for the help

Comment: What's the browser you're using? Usually, it should work when you remove margin and padding in HTML and body tag.

Comment: Do you have some other margins in your css?

Comment: I'm using both firefox and chrome. Both have this same problem.

I do not have any other margins on my css, they are all empty except for the things I wrote so the margins dissapeared

Tried the answers and they didn't work. I can't put it as background image because the images are variable. This is for an image viewer program that changes images on variable times so it has to be more than one image.

Comment: write a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Your image is too small to cover the entire window/document, however try these solutions:

**First way:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Something</h3>
    <img class"image" src="..." alt="";
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
```

**Second way:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Something</h3>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background-image: url('...image path here...');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```